# Timeline chart in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, reporting-services-2012

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yKyX.png)

like the above i need to create ssrs report .

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('RANDD') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROC RANDD
GO 

--EXEC RANDD 1

CREATE  PROC [dbo].RANDD

@Reg INT 

AS 

BEGIN 

SET NOCOUNT ON 


IF object_ID ('tempdb..#Chart')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Chart


    CREATE TABLE #Chart
    (
      CurrentHr FLOAT ,
      CurrentCyc FLOAT ,
      RegID     INT ,
      Reg     nvarchar(max)

    )

    INSERT INTO #Chart (CurrentHr, CurrentCyc,RegID,Reg ) 
        VALUES  
                (120,10,@Reg,'Aircraft'),
                (120,20,@Reg,'Aircraft'),
                (100,30,@Reg,'Aircraft'),
                (80,40,@Reg,'Aircraft'),
                (60,50,@Reg,'Aircraft');


                ;with Cte AS 
(
SELECT  DISTINCT TOP 1


         tReg.ID                        AS 'RegID'
        ,tReg.Reg                       AS 'Reg'    
        ,(SELECT  TOP 1 dbo.FormatedLifeCodeValue(tLifeCode_ID,tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.LifeTotal,1)
                        FROM tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents
                        JOIN tRegJourneyLogBook     ON tRegJourneyLogBook.ID = tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.tRegJourneyLogBook_ID
                        JOIN tRegJourney            ON tRegJourney.ID = tRegJourneyLogBook.tRegJourney_ID
                        JOIN tLogBook               ON tLogBook.ID = tRegJourneyLogBook.tLogBook_ID 
                                                    AND tLogBook.tAsset_ID =  tReg.tAsset_ID
                        JOIN tLifeCode              ON tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.tLifeCode_ID = tLifeCode.ID   
                        WHERE tLifeCode.RegJourneyHours = 1 
                       ORDER BY tRegJourney.TakeOffTime DESC)                   AS 'Current Hours'

                        ,(SELECT  TOP 1 --dbo.FormatedLifeCodeValue(tLifeCode_ID,tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.LifeTotal,1)
                        CAST(ROUND(CAST(tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.LifeTotal  /60 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),0)AS FLOAT)
                        FROM tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents
                        JOIN tRegJourneyLogBook     ON tRegJourneyLogBook.ID = tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.tRegJourneyLogBook_ID
                        JOIN tRegJourney            ON tRegJourney.ID = tRegJourneyLogBook.tRegJourney_ID
                        JOIN tLogBook               ON tLogBook.ID = tRegJourneyLogBook.tLogBook_ID 
                                                    AND tLogBook.tAsset_ID =  tReg.tAsset_ID
                        JOIN tLifeCode              ON tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.tLifeCode_ID = tLifeCode.ID   
                        WHERE tLifeCode.RegJourneyHours = 1 
                       ORDER BY tRegJourney.TakeOffTime DESC)                   AS CurrentHours

         ,(SELECT  TOP 1 dbo.FormatedLifeCodeValue(tLifeCode_ID,tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.LifeTotal,1)
                        --CAST((ROUND(tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.LifeTotal/60,0) )AS DECIMAL(10,0))
                        FROM tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents
                        JOIN tRegJourneyLogBook     ON tRegJourneyLogBook.ID = tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.tRegJourneyLogBook_ID
                        JOIN tRegJourney            ON tRegJourney.ID = tRegJourneyLogBook.tRegJourney_ID
                        JOIN tLogBook               ON tLogBook.ID = tRegJourneyLogBook.tLogBook_ID AND tLogBook.tAsset_ID =  tReg.tAsset_ID
                        JOIN tLifeCode              ON tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.tLifeCode_ID = tLifeCode.ID   
                        WHERE tLifeCode.RegJourneyLandings = 1 
                       ORDER BY tRegJourney.TakeOffTime DESC )                  AS 'Current CyclesOrig'

                             ,(SELECT  TOP 1 CAST(tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.LifeTotal AS DECIMAL(10,0))
                      --  CAST((ROUND(tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.LifeTotal/60,0) )AS DECIMAL(10,0))
                        FROM tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents
                        JOIN tRegJourneyLogBook     ON tRegJourneyLogBook.ID = tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.tRegJourneyLogBook_ID
                        JOIN tRegJourney            ON tRegJourney.ID = tRegJourneyLogBook.tRegJourney_ID
                        JOIN tLogBook               ON tLogBook.ID = tRegJourneyLogBook.tLogBook_ID AND tLogBook.tAsset_ID =  tReg.tAsset_ID
                        JOIN tLifeCode              ON tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.tLifeCode_ID = tLifeCode.ID   
                        WHERE tLifeCode.RegJourneyLandings = 1 
                       ORDER BY tRegJourney.TakeOffTime DESC )                  AS 'CurrentCycles'


FROM tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents

JOIN tRegJourneyLogBook ON tRegJourneyLogBook.ID = tRegJourneyLogBookLifeCodeEvents.tRegJourneyLogBook_ID
JOIN tRegJourney ON tRegJourney.ID = tRegJourneyLogBook.tRegJourney_ID
JOIN tReg ON tReg.ID = tRegJourney.tReg_ID
JOIN tLogBook ON tLogBook.ID = tRegJourneyLogBook.tLogBook_ID AND tLogBook.tAsset_ID = tReg.tAsset_ID

WHERE tReg.ID IN (@Reg)

)
SELECT ROUND(CAST(CAST(Cte.CurrentCycles / CAST (1000 AS DECIMAL (10,3)) AS DECIMAL(9,6)) AS FLOAT ),0) AS CurrentCyc1 ,
ROUND(CAST(CAST(Cte.CurrentHours / CAST (1000 AS DECIMAL (10,3)) AS DECIMAL(9,6)) AS FLOAT ),0) AS CurrentHr1 ,RegID AS REGI,Reg AS RG 

 into #temp FROM Cte


update #temp SET REGI = 0 WHERE (REGI) >1 

SELECT * into #temp2 FROM #temp

--select * from #temp2

select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RegID) AS AA 
into #temp3 from #temp2 RIGHT JOIN #Chart on #Chart.RegID = #temp2.REGI

update #temp3 SET CurrentCyc1 = 0 WHERE (AA) > 1

update #temp3 SET CurrentHr1 = 0 WHERE (AA) > 1

SELECT * FROM #temp3

--EXEC RANDD 1

Drop table #temp
DROP table #temp2 
DROP table #temp3 

SET NOCOUNT OFF 

END
```

this above is my stored Procedure and its result set would be .

below 
atatched image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4z6k.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There is a question here some place, I just can't see it. You have the data, what have you tried? Create something in SSRS and see what happens.